# Nftables management problem

Tags: nftables

I've migrated from iptables to nftables and have one annoying problem. In the old system I had a script which removed/added a few rules each day. I was able to easily add/delete iptables rules by their position, which was CONSTANT.

Now we have annoying handles. When I add a rule from the script, it gets assigned by dynamic handle number. I can delete rule by retrieving this handle number at first. The problem is that when the same rule gets deleted and re-added. after that, its handle number gets incremented, so is not the same. So I'm not able to use the same simple approach as I had in my old system.

Can anyone give me a solution for this problem - chain has at least 40 rules in it, and I want to delete re-add the same rule several rules each day. It was so easy with iptables, and now I can't find easy solution

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give examples what these rules are (nft commands or ruleset dump), so that better understanding for giving answer is provided? Thanks.

Comment: There are surely other ways than trying to handle the ... handle. But this requires seeing an example of your ruleset first, as raspi already asked. And an explanation of the need to frequently change this rule (eg: some dynamic DNS resolution requiring to update an IP address?).

Comment: Here is an excerpt from my ruleset:

   add rule ip nat postrouting oifname $inet_if ip saddr 172.xx.xx.xx counter snat to $inet_if_ip
   add rule ip nat postrouting oifname $inet_if ip saddr 172.xx.xx.xx counter snat to $inet_if_ip`
...and so on...

So my wish is very simple, I want to remove and re-add some rules from this chain (40 such rules in it) each single day. For example I want to remove and re-add after some time second, third and seventh rule. This was so easy with iptables and now its so hard with nftables:(

Comment: sorry but you describe *how* you intend to do it, not *why* you intend to do it. Can you explain why? Explaining how you think it should be done without why can lead to the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: But I don't understand, because of nftables lacks this usefull feature I must explain why do I need to remove particular rules from nftables? Why is it so importent? All I want to do is to remove several rules at 23:00 and re-add them at 6:00. Very easy task with iptables. As you insist on knowing why - I want to disable internet access for some users at that time and re-enable it in the morning. Do I need to call users names?

Comment: If the rules are either about IP addresses or UIDs (which can be displayed as user names too) yes I would like to know, and even see them. Please bear with me. Switching to a newer tool usually requires switching older use habits to newer use habits which are not always the same.

Comment: The reason it lacks this feature is about how nftables works vs iptables. iptables, to add or remove 1 rule actually replaces the whole ruleset every time. To add the 1000001th rule, iptables download the 1000000 rules, add one, then sends back to the kernel 1000001 rules: quite slow to add *one* rule. nftables sends only the delta of one rule to the kernel. That's related to the lack of the feature you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, so I thought I wrote very clearly, I have at least 40 following rules "add rule ip nat postrouting oifname $inet_if ip saddr 172.xx.xx.xx counter snat to $inet_if_ip". Each rule is for different IP address. What would be your suggested new solution to replace my simple old one - remove some of these rules at 23:00 and re-add the same rules at 06:00?

Answer (score 5):

[OP uses this kind of rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609873/nftables-management-problem?noredirect=1#comment1138619_609873), that's the layout I'll use as example to base the answer upon:

> ```
> add rule ip nat postrouting oifname $inet_if ip saddr 172.xx.xx.xx counter snat to $inet_if_ip
> add rule ip nat postrouting oifname $inet_if ip saddr 172.xx.xx.xx counter snat to $inet_if_ip
> ```
>
> ...and so on...

### Using a set

*nftables* features [sets](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets#Named_sets), something similar to the *ipset* companion to iptables, but more generic.

It's thus possible to factorize the *nat* rules into one rule and then manipulate only the associated set without touching the rule anymore. The manipulation of set elements, including deletion, doesn't need any handle because contrary to rules its content order is irrelevant so it can be efficiently searched and reordered in kernel memory using a hashed list.

If counting independent *nat* flows (ie: keeping the role of the `counter` is important, this requires recent tools (at least >= 0.9.1 but nftables >= 0.9.4 is recommended, see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607386/using-nft-to-count-bytes-on-a-dynamic-set-of-saddr/607509#607509) on this, but also see "bugs" at the end of this answer). *nftables* is still evolving, so some features are dependent of the version of *nftables* or the kernel.

nftables <s>0.9.6</s> 0.9.8 was used in this answer. This can affect some syntax and features (like JSON).

So instead of this kind of ruleset:

```
define inet_if = eth0
define inet_if_ip = 192.0.2.2

table ip nat        # for idempotency
delete table ip nat # for idempotency

table ip nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        oifname $inet_if ip saddr 172.17.1.2 counter snat to $inet_if_ip
        oifname $inet_if ip saddr 172.17.1.3 counter snat to $inet_if_ip
    }
}
```

one can use a set that can be populated later (or could be directly too):

```
define inet_if = eth0
define inet_if_ip = 192.0.2.2

table ip nat
delete table ip nat

table ip nat {
    set curfewlist {
        type ipv4_addr
        counter        # optional
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        oifname $inet_if ip saddr @curfewlist snat to $inet_if_ip
    }
}
```

The set can then be populated in crontab at 06:00 with (following the previous example):

```
nft 'add element ip nat curfewlist { 172.17.1.2, 172.17.1.3 }'
```

At 23:00, It can then be deleted element by element:

```
nft 'delete element ip nat curfewlist { 172.17.1.2 }'
nft 'delete element ip nat curfewlist { 172.17.1.3 }'
```

or multiple elements at once:

```
nft 'delete element ip nat curfewlist { 172.17.1.2, 172.17.1.3 }'
```

or simply flushed:

```
nft flush set ip nat curfewlist
```

Note: the scope (aka the namespace) of a *set* is within its table: a set can't be referenced from an other table, but contrary to *iptables* a table isn't limited to one hook type. One can and *probably should* have multiple types of chains in the same table, allowing to reuse the same set for example in a *filter* rule and in a *nat* rule, rather than mimicing *iptables*' limit of one hook type per table.

### Using the `meta hour` match

With kernel >= 5.5, there's not even need to alter anything anymore, with the use of [`meta hour`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8#META_EXPRESSIONS) that can do the check in the packet path. The single *nat* rule can be replaced with:

```
meta hour 06:00-23:00 oifname $inet_if ip saddr @curfewlist snat to $inet_if_ip
```

And the set left permanently filled. Only twice a year, during Daylight Saving Time changes should the ruleset be reloaded, since the kernel always works with UTC time. The complete ruleset would be:

```
define inet_if = eth0
define inet_if_ip = 192.0.2.2

table ip nat
delete table ip nat

table ip nat {
    set curfewlist {
        type ipv4_addr
        counter
        elements = { 172.17.1.2, 172.17.1.3 }
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        meta hour 06:00-23:00 oifname $inet_if ip saddr @curfewlist snat to $inet_if_ip
    }
}
```

Note: the hour interval stored in kernel's memory is in UTC timezone and always a single continuous interval modulo 24h. Depending on the local timezone, the hour expression could be read back differently, like `!= "23:00"-"06:00"`, which means the same as `"06:00"-"23:00"`.

---

While I think above simplifies the result, below I'll present how to work around or still try and use handles in other ways.

### Avoiding the need to manipulate a handle

If methods above aren't adequate for the use case, you can still move all logical rules in an user chain and do operations at the chain level instead of the rule level. This gives here:

```
define inet_if = eth0

table ip nat
delete table ip nat

table ip nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
        oifname $inet_if jump curfew
    }

    chain curfew { }
}
```

at 06:00 one would load the following ruleset part (eg with: `nft -f curfew.nft`):

```
define inet_if_ip = 192.0.2.2

flush chain ip nat curfew #for idempotency

table ip nat {
    chain curfew {
        ip saddr 172.17.1.2 counter snat to $inet_if_ip
        ip saddr 172.17.1.3 counter snat to $inet_if_ip
    }
}
```

and at 23:00 simply run this command:

```
nft flush chain ip nat curfew
```

### Any other method to still use the handle?

This requires one way or an other the use of scripts rather than only *nft*.

Trying to identify rules later requires to dump *all* the chain's rules (ie: transfer them from kernel to userland). This is what *nftables*' developpers have been trying to avoid from the start.

If you plan to add rule that might be deleted later in a given use case, store their handle when they are added, that way there won't be the need to lookup the handle later.

Using `--echo` along the `--handle` option will display back atomically what was just added, including the handle (running separately `nft --handle monitor` would also work). With the previous `curfew.nft` file that would give (with the handles changing at each invocation):

```
# nft --echo --handle -f curfew.nft 
add chain ip nat curfew # handle 2
add rule ip nat curfew ip saddr 172.17.1.2 counter packets 0 bytes 0 snat to 192.0.2.2 # handle 4
add rule ip nat curfew ip saddr 172.17.1.3 counter packets 0 bytes 0 snat to 192.0.2.2 # handle 5
```

So running again with a reasonable filter (made easier by knowing what is added in this specific ruleset part):

```
# nft --echo --handle -f curfew.nft | sed -n 's/^add rule.*# handle \(.*\)$/\1/p' | tee curfew-handles.txt
6
7
```

One can append manually an additional rule and also store its handle:

```
# nft --echo --handle add rule ip nat curfew ip saddr 172.17.1.4 snat to 192.0.2.2 | sed -n 's/^add rule.*# handle \(.*\)$/\1/p' | tee -a curfew-handles.txt
8
```

and later delete all the rules by handle in the list:

```
# for i in $(cat curfew-handles.txt); do printf 'delete rule ip nat curfew handle %d\n' $i; done | nft -f - && : > curfew-handles.txt
```

**UPDATE**: better JSON support with nftables >= 0.9.8

*nftables* supports [JSON output](https://manpages.debian.org/libnftables-json.5), but requires version 0.9.8: `nft --echo --handle --json add rule ...` echoes back nothing on version 0.9.6, but works properly on 0.9.8 (and tested here with kernel 5.10.x).

Example to retrieve the handle of the rule just added, using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). The additional output comment line itself isn't JSON output so has to be filtered out:

```
# nft --echo --json add rule ip nat curfew ip saddr 172.17.1.4 snat to 192.0.2.2 | 
    grep -v '^#' | 
    jq '.nftables[].add.rule.handle'
40
```

Or using `nft monitor` at the same time, while providing chain information along the rule, to be more useful in this context:

```
nft --json monitor | 
    grep --line-buffered -v '^#' |
    jq -j '
        .add.rule |
            if . != null then
                (.handle, " ", .family, " ", .table, " ", .chain, "\n")
            else
                empty
            end'
```

Result when the previous rule command above is made:

```
40 ip nat curfew
```

Caveat:

- bugs in some nftables versions

  currently (v0.9.8), using `--echo --handle` on some complete rulesets can cause `nft` to emit warnings (when the ruleset right before was empty) or even to crash (eg: it appears the quite recently introduced `counter` keyword in sets will crash such command or a running `nft --handle monitor`). For now better stick to using this on commands simply adding rules.

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```bsh
handle=$(nft list ruleset -a | grep "$your_rule" | grep "#" | awk '{print $NF}')
test -n "$handle" && nft delete rule filter output handle "$handle"
nft insert rule filter output position XX ...
```

Comment: Don't you feel the irony - I was able to do this with the simple iptables command and now I need to use script for this? :) And this will not work completely as I have at least 40 very similar rules in nat table and I want to remove for example second, sixth and eight rule which differs slightly.

Comment: You can still use iptables. I believe they will be here for at least ten more years.

Comment: Yeah, I can use iptables, but I thought that nftables is better version of iptables. And it is very strange that they lack such needed feature:(

Comment: Open Source is mostly developed by the "I need this feature" basis where "I" is an open source developer. Then there are companies which pay for features they need. The average user needs are most often dismissed unless the developer also wants to get them.

Answer (score 1):

## What I would do

Ise a custom table, and replace it each time. Table updates are atomic if done with a single call to `nft`.

So change the rules in my program, re-generate the table, call `nft`.

Answer (score 1):

Element timeouts may provide the solution you need. You can place the addresses or ports in a set, from which they will be removed automatically upon expiration.

Timeouts can be specified in hours, minutes, seconds or a combination such as 2h10m5s.

Quoting and example from the nftables wiki:

```
% nft add table inet myfilter
% nft add set inet myfilter myset {type ipv4_addr\; flags timeout\; }
% nft add element inet myfilter myset {10.0.0.1 timeout 10s }
```

Result:

```
% nft list ruleset
table inet myfilter {
    set myset {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags timeout
        elements = { 10.0.0.1 timeout 10s expires 8s}
    }
}
```

Source: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Element_timeouts